# Parsing JSON from a URL (PHP CURL)

Tags: php, json, parsing

So I've been stumped and I'm not sure how I would continue this
as an example let's just use `books.com` as the URL and let's say the JSON response from the URL is

```
[{"title":"first_title","description":"second_title"},
{"title":"second_title","description":"second_description"}]
```

How would I print **all** of the titles *(just the titles)* without knowing exactly how many there are.

I know that I would need to loop through the JSON but I'm unsure how, if I could have any guidance that would be fantastic.

Comment: Can you show some code of what you've tried so far? [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This key is to actually convert the JSON response into a PHP associative array by using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then loop through it.

```
// Convert the JSON into a PHP  associative Array 
$response = json_decode($curlResponse,true);

// Loop through the array
foreach ($response as $value) {
    echo $value['title'];
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get more familiar with [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).
First you need to decode json (into array in this example) and then iterate through all elements.

Example of working code:

```
<?php

$json = '[{"title":"first_title","description":"second_title"},
{"title":"second_title","description":"second_description"}]';

$jsonArray = json_decode($json,true);

foreach($jsonArray as $entry) {
    echo $entry['title'].'<br>';    
}
```

Output:

```
first_title
second_title
```